# Sometimes gets an error "match.map is not a function" - in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I'm new here on the site. I have a problem with the react that I have been trying to solve for a long time but can't figure out what it is.

I sometimes get an error, not always. .Map is not a function
I do not understand why.

I think in the middle of the program, something happens to the match array, because then the map does not work, I'm not sure where that happens.

match.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getMatch } from '../redux/actions/dataActions';

import Match from '../components/match/Match';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class match extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getMatch();
        console.log(this.props.data);
    }
    render() {
        const { loading, match} = this.props.data;
        console.log(this.props.data);
        let recentScreamsMarkup = !loading ? (
            match.map((singleMatch) => <Match key={singleMatch.userHandle} match={singleMatch} />)
        ) : ();
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={6} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.data
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getMatch }
)(match);
```

Match.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// MUI Stuff
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
// Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const styles = {
  card: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  image: {
    minWidth: 200
  },
  content: {
    padding: 25,
    objectFit: 'cover'
  }
};

class Match extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      match: {
        userHandle,
      },
      user: {
        credentials: { handle },
      }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent className={classes.content}>
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            component={Link}
            to={`/users/${userHandle}`}
            color="primary"
          >
            {userHandle}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Match));
```

the getMatch function in nodeJs , the action:

```
export const getMatch = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get('/kmeansHandleArray')
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_MATCH,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_MATCH,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};
```

the reducer of getMatch function

```
        case GET_MATCH:
          return {
            ...state,
            match: action.payload,
            loading: false
          };
```

post Scriptum. getMatch is a function that works 100%, it returns an array that contains objects:
For example, it can return something of the form:

```
[
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_7",
        "userHandle": "test500"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_5",
        "userHandle": "devops2"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_6",
        "userHandle": "mobile2"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_3",
        "userHandle": "backend3"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_4",
        "userHandle": "devops1"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_2",
        "userHandle": "backend2"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_10",
        "userHandle": "testtttttt"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_9",
        "userHandle": "testing200"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_8",
        "userHandle": "testing100"
    },
    {
        "matchNumber": "match_1",
        "userHandle": "backend1"
    }
]
```

Comment: What does your console log show for the various values of `this.props.data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is a common problem on rendering arrays or list in react, you need to check with a condition if match exists as list or if this have valid values:

i put a lenght validation, can you try this on your code?

```js
 render() {
        const { loading, match} = this.props.data;
        console.log(this.props.data);
        let recentScreamsMarkup = !loading ? (
            match.length > 0 && //-->try adding tris validation!
            match.map((singleMatch) => <Match key={singleMatch.userHandle} match={singleMatch} />)
        ) : ();
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={6} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! its work, to be honest i'm not 100% sure why, but its work well now

Comment: that is a behavior because of the render in the virtual dom, just try to validate and your gonna to be just fine :), your welcome

Comment: OP gets a ".map is not a function" error thus "match.length > 0" would equally fail if match is undefined || null. I'd play it save and validate check "match" using " ... Array.isArray(match) && ..."

Answer (score 1):

Validate **match** is an Array.

```
let recentScreamsMarkup = !loading && Array.isArray(match) ? (
    match.map(singleMatch =>
     <Match key={singleMatch.userHandle} match={singleMatch} />
    )) : ();
```

Alternatively, set a default value during deconstruction:

```
const { loading, match = [] } = this.props.data;
```

Also, some API's return arrays with only 1 item as an object so you could  do something like this to always work with an array:

```
let { loading, match } = this.props.data;
match = match ? Array.isArray(match) ? match : [match] : []
```